# git flow: 2 feature branches that share components, how to sync them?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using git flow for my projects and I'm having a question in relation to finding the right approach to an issue I'm having.

I have my `develop` branch and started `feature/stores`. I've changed quite a few things in parts of the code that will be used in my next feature: `feature/user`.

However, my develop hasn't been updated with `feature/stores` yet (it's not yet finished), but `feature/user` will have to use some stuff I did in `feature/stores`.

Do I just branch off of the (outdated) `develop` branch and then resvolve the merge conflicts later (with the chance of not being 100% certain what's supposed to be there), or can I somehow use the unfinished `feature/stores` branch as a start for my `feature/user` branch and keep it updated?

Comment: You could cherry pick the individual commits/files that have the changes you need. You would pick them from the `stores` branch into the `user` branch. Though there is nothing really "wrong" with just starting the new branch from `stores`.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not familiar with cherry picking yet, but it seems like a form of rebasing.

It's difficult to say if this is what I want/need and if it's worth it.

I might just branch off of `develop` and fix any merge conflicts down the line to keep my branches clean.

Comment: As long as you aren't duplicating work just do whatever is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

In the git-flow, features need to be independant.

you need to finish your first feature before. If you have commons changes, depends of your project, you can stash file, go to develop and push the files which are in common.

After you rebase your twos features on the new develop commit. I think this is the cleanest.